# How do I change a group of arguments separated by a space to become one argument in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make a bot with a command which warns someone in a DM. What I have is that the first argument would be `/ticket`, and the 2nd argument would be a mention, then the 3rd argument would be the first word of the reason, and the 4th would be the 2nd word of the reason and so forth. What I am having trouble doing is changing the 3rd argument to the end of the reason be 1 argument. So here's my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const token = 'token here';
const PREFIX = '/';
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
bot.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log('This bot is online! Created by @littleBitsman.');

bot.on('message', message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'ticket':
      if (message.member.roles.highest == '701895573737046066') {
        mention = message.mentions.users.first()
        var thing = args.shift()
        thing = args.shift()
        var reason 
        reason = args.shift()
        mentionID = mention.id
        if(mention = null) {return}
        var messagetosend = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Ticket')
          .setDescription('Hey ' + thing + '! You recieved this because of: ' + reason + '.')
        message.client.users.fetch(`${mentionID}`).then(user => user.send(messagetosend))
      }
      }
  })
bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change approach, if I understand right, the command is like this:
/ticket @person  bad behaviour

And the message should be: Hey person! You received this because of: bad behaviour

So I would make it like this:

```
mention = message.mentions.users.first()
if(mention === null) return
args.splice(0,2) //removes prefix and mention 
reason = args.join(" ")
var messagetosend = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Ticket')
          .setDescription('Hey  ' + mention + '! You received this because of: ' + reason + '.')
        message.client.users.fetch(mentionID).then(user => user.send(messagetosend))
```

Change it how you like

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `args` has just an array of words, all of which make up the reason.

So why not do this:

```js
// sample args
let args = ["you", "forgot", "to", "turn", "it", "on"];

let reason = args.join(' ');

console.log('reason:' + reason);
// reason: you forgot to turn it on
```